# Help with formatting headers

Tags: fonts, formatting, header-footer, fontsize

People. I am new person to LaTeX. I wasted a lot of time for these easy things... I am sorry to interrupt all of you.

oh, I am trying my best to find solution to these problems. But everytime something doesn't work.

So, 
1) I want to remove a final dot in headings in the top of a page. (it is marked by red colour)

2) I want to remove a space between number of chapter and `chaptermark` in headings in the top of a page. (it is marked by blue colour)

3) I want to reduce size of font of `chaptername` (it is marked by yellow)

4) Now in table of content there is 
1
1.1 Линейные...

but I want 
Билет 1 - it is \chaptermark
1.1 Линейные...

But I want to save that is written in headings and names of chapter. So, content on this screenshot should remain the same. But problem is in tableofcontent.

```
  %document information
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,longtable} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amstext,amssymb,amscd}                       
\usepackage[margin=2.3cm, footskip = 1 cm, headheight=36pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\  \thechapter}{0pt}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead [CE] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \rightmark}}
\fancyhead [CO] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \leftmark}} 


% page settings
\frenchspacing 
\parindent=1cm
\sloppy
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Билет №}
\makeatother


\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
    \addtocounter{page}{0}%
    \newpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter[]{Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения с переменными коэффициентами. Фундаментальная система решений. Определитель Вронского. Формула Лиувилля-Остроградского.}

\section{Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения с переменными коэффициентами.}

\blankpage
\blankpage
\blankpage

\chapter{hello}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't address your questions, but will help "clean up" your preamble.  `amsmath` loads `amstext`, so the latter isn't needed.  `amssmyb` loads `amsfonts`, so that one isn't needed either.

Comment: … and I wouldn't recommend `amscd` for commutative diagrams nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, I will learn your advices... But I still don't know how to make my wishes reality... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reducing the font size in chapter titles, use `\Large` instead of `\LARGE`.

For removing the period in the header, change the definition of `\chaptermark`.

For the space, remove it from the `\titlesec` instructions.

I also added `\raggedright`, that helps in case your titles are so long as in the example.

Note that `cmap` shouldn't be necessary; also `\frenchspacing` is automatic with Russian. In the code below I omitted all unnecessary packages.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% packages
%\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=2.3cm, footskip = 1 cm, headheight=36pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{2ex}{}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead [CE] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \rightmark}}
\fancyhead [CO] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 \chaptertitlename\thechapter\fi}{}%
}


\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Билет №}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения с переменными коэффициентами. 
Фундаментальная система решений. Определитель Вронского. Формула Лиувилля-Остроградского.}

\section[Линейные обыкновенные]{Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения с переменными 
коэффициентами.}

Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения с переменными
коэффициентами.

\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage
\mbox{}\clearpage

\chapter{hello}

\end{document}
```

### Chapter title

[image]

### Header

[image]

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. But I am tried to solve 3 something like you. But I've copied here wrong test code. So, I want exactly the same as it is at my screenshot, but less. But your variant is different because there is no new line. And I don't how to add it. \\ \\* \\newline have no impact.

And I am also should update this page because I've forgotten to say about 4-th problem.


And in your header there is a space, isn't it? 


I understand that it is not so important, but I want to know...

Comment: @Dida Sorry for the space, I fixed it (in the definition of `\chaptermark`). I'm not sure what you mean about the new line. Do you *really* mean to have titles as long as those *and* fully report them in the header?

Comment: No! 
Now in headers everythings is OK.

I mean new line between chaptermark and chaptername. As usual settings, without packages. and take a look with problem with table of content, please. I am so grateful to you.

Comment: @Dida Your code didn't specify that “Билет №1” should be on a line by itself. I'll add it.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly have new question. 
I know that it is possible to add/delete info from table of content.
But how to EDIT it?
For example, I want, 
"Линейные обыкновенные дифференциальные уравнения \\ с переменными коэффициентами.........."

How can I get this \\ ?

Comment: @Dida It doesn't work like this. Please, make a new question specifying precisely what you want to obtain. But first of all, try hard and avoid long titles: they help nobody.